# Document Snapshot listener not working when same view controller is loaded in another tab! - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is an example picture for explaining a problem in my project.

[image]

I have a tabbed view controller here, in one tab i have **Guide Profile List**, in other tab i have **List of Chats** i have done.

There is a single chatScreenViewController.. (example picture like this)

[image]

this single chat view controller loads up in 2 ways,
(1) when i click any conversation from list of conversations in chats tab.
(2) In guide profile screen there is a **Chat** button, when i click that chat button which instantiate a singleChatViewController and loads up in navigation stack.

whenever this view controller is loaded this function is called, i.e. this function adds a listner to a document of firebase so that it may listen to any messages that are sent.

```
func loadUpChatModel()
{
    guard let chateeInfo = self.chateeInfoStruct
    else
    {
        print("chateeInfoStruct from previous vc is not set")
        return
    }
    
    let chatId = chateeInfo.chatId
    setTouristReadValueToTrue(chatId: chatId)
    
    let chatRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("chats").document(chatId)
    self.listner = chatRef.addSnapshotListener
    { (chatDocument, error) in
        if let err = error
        {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            print("error getting a chat document")
        }
        else
        {
            if chatDocument != nil, chatDocument!.exists
            {
                guard let data = chatDocument!.data()
                else
                {
                    print("unable to convert data of single chat for chat list model")
                    return
                }
        
                if let model = self.chatModel
                {
                    let oldTotalMessages = model.totalMessages!
                    let newTotalMessages = data["totalMessages"] as! Int
                    let messagesAdded = newTotalMessages - oldTotalMessages
                    var i = 0
                    while i < messagesAdded
                    {
                        let message = data["message\(oldTotalMessages+i+1)"] as? String ?? "Unable to retrieve"
                        let messageSentStatus = data["message\(oldTotalMessages+i+1)sent"] as? Bool ?? false
                        let block = messageBlock(message: message, messageWasSent: messageSentStatus)
                        self.chatModel!.messagesArray.append(block)
                        i += 1
                    }
                    self.chatModel!.lastMessageDate = data["lastMessageDate"] as? String ?? "date not found for this chat"
                    self.chatModel!.totalMessages = newTotalMessages
                    self.updateTableView()
                }
                else
                {
                    let lastMessageDate = data["lastMessageDate"] as? String ?? "date not found for this chat"
                    let totalMessages = data["totalMessages"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let singleChatModel = SingleChatDM(chatId: chatId, lastMessageDate: lastMessageDate, totalMessages: totalMessages)
                    var i = 0
                    while i < totalMessages
                    {
                        let message = data["message\(i+1)"] as? String ?? "Unable to retrieve"
                        let messageSentStatus = data["message\(i+1)sent"] as? Bool ?? false
                        let block = messageBlock(message: message, messageWasSent: messageSentStatus)
                        singleChatModel.messagesArray.append(block)
                        i += 1
                    }
                    self.chatModel = singleChatModel
                    self.updateTableView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i open a single chat in one tab, it works fine, messages are sent and received and table view loads correctly.
BUT, when i load this view controller in other tab also by clicking on chat button from same guide profile whose single chat is loaded in other tab, the problem arise.
Now when i send the message the data is correctly stored to firebase document but my table view is not updated, i cannot see the new messages i sent in both of the view controllers. (This is very much according to me is because i am not receiving any updated document snapshots i.e. listener is not working).

any help about this behaviour!! I searched for but i could not found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for an active view controller by a super global variable, if that variable is set, then instead of again loading that view controller make that tab active in which your chat view controller is already loaded. Not a permanent solution but i think this may work !!

Comment: Thank you so much for help, while implementing your idea, i found out that i had made a wrong implementation of viewWillDisappear, in which i am removing the listener, and whenever i change the tab, the method gets called and listener was eventually removed. I used self.view.isMovingFromParent property to remove the listener and that did the worked. It seems like a forever stuck before, lol. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Glad to help you @AmaisSheikh, anytime!